# Ionic cordova run android

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Compañeros tengo un problema al momento de ejecutar mi aplicacion de ionic con el comando `ionic cordova run android` pero recibo un error como este

```
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

Cuando lo ejecuto desde android studio lo hace de la manera correcta, creo que tiene que ver con algo relacionado con el Gradle:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

por favor alguna sugerencia para arreglar este inconveniente, desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Vengo tarde pero espero ayudar a los próximos visitantes:

Hay una serie de pasos que debes seguir para tener el entorno listo para la ejecución.

### Compilación

#### Pre-requisitos

Para compilar la aplicación como `.apk` es necesario hacer unas configuraciones previas

- Instalar [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/)

Nos descargamos el `.zip` y lo descomprimimos en `c:\Gradle`.

En Variables del sistema deberemos añadir en `path`:

```
C:\Gradle\gradle-6.4.1\bin
```

- Instalar [JDK 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)

*Nota: Actualmente la versión es JDK 14, pero sólo el JDK8 tienes las librerías necesarias para la compilación*

Tras descargar e instalar JDK, deberemos configurar las variables de entorno:

En variables para el usuario:

```
JAVA_HOME = D:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.8.0_251
PATH += D:\Archivos de programa\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que en el path se añade una línea más.

- Instalar [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)

Esto instalará un IDE y las SDK Tools de Android para el funcionamiento, posteriormente deberemos configurar las variables de entorno:

```
ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\Archivos de programa\Android
```

En el `path` deberemos añadir las siguientes líneas:

```
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools
```

- Aceptar las licencias

Antes de nada hay que aceptar las licencias de Android SDK.

Ejecutamos en el `cmd` el siguiente comando:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
```

y aceptamos con `y` todas las licencias.

Espero haberte ayudado a que tu proyecto funcione perfectamente.

Answer (score 0):

Espero y alguien más le pueda ayudar este comando.

```
npm i -g native-run
```

Puede seguir la respuesta en el forum de ionic
[native run issue](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-cordova-run-android-native-run-issue/165378)

Answer (score -2):

Misma experiencia en Windows:

1. Descárgate el binario desde https://gradle.org/releases/
2. Extrae el contenido donde quieras
3. Agregar al Path de las variables entorno, la ruta /path/to/gragle/bin